# How should I reference an IHttpModule instance in the pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpmodule

An IHttpModule implementation I created

```
public class ResponseTweaker : IHttpModule {  // my module ...
```

is registered in Web.config

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="redman" type="ResponseTweaker"/>
  </httpModules>
```

and an instance of it is sitting in the pipeline.

From the perspective of a caller (e.g. from the Global.asax.cs file), **how *should* I get a reference to that module instance?**

Comment: https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles/blob/master/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles/PerHttpApplicationLifestyleManager.cs#L37

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modules can be found in `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules`.

You can look through the `HttpModuleCollection`, or use the name syntax:
`HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules["redman"]`. You will probably need to cast the returned `IHttpModule` to type `ResponseTweaker`.

If the type may vary, search the collection to find module(s) matching the desired type.

Comment: That's just what the doctor ordered. Thanks.